# Error when adding and styling Angular-Google-Chart

Tags: angular, charts, google-visualization

I have a angular google (bar)chart:

```
<google-chart
  [data]="data" 
  [columns]="dataColumns"
  [type]="chartType"
  [options]="options" >
</google-chart>
```

```
chartType = "BarChart";

  options = {
    backgroundColor: 'transparent',
    colors: ['#ffa500']
  }

  dataColumns= [
    ['Name', {role: 'data'}],
    ['Data', {role: 'data'}],
    ['Color', { role: 'style'}],
    [{ role: 'annotation'}]
  ]

  data= [
    ['name1', 10, 'red', 'text'],
    ['name2', 8, 'green', 'text'],
    ['name3', 5, 'blue', 'text'],
  ];
```

Now I get this message: "All series on a given axis must be of the same data type". What does this mean and how to fix it?

And I have one additional question: There are these vertical lines inside the chart, how do I disable them?

Answer (score 0):

to remove the vertical gridlines,
use the following `hAxis` options...

```
options = {
  hAxis: {
    gridlines: {
      count: 0
    }
  },
  backgroundColor: 'transparent',
  colors: ['#ffa500']
}
```

to correct the error about data type,
use the following columns...

```
dataColumns = ['Name', 'Data', {role: 'style'}, {role: 'annotation'}]
```